# Subjunctive future or imperative when conjugating a verb denoting a "general act"

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo, conjugación, imperativo, futuro

"General act" isn't a very descriptive phrase here, but let me show what I mean.

> When you address an old person, you **use** *usted* instead of *tú*.

The verb of interest is in bold letters. In Spanish, would this sentence translate to:

> Cuándo dirigir una persona mayore, **usares** *usted* en vez de *tú*.

Or

> Cuándo dirigir una persona mayore, **usa** *usted* en vez de *tú*.

Or should it be conjugated in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To talk about such general actions, it is common to use [pasiva refleja](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables) with the *se* pronoun, instead of "tú":

- Cuando se habla con una persona mayor, se usa *usted* en vez de *tú*.

If you want to use *tú* (or *usted*), you need to use the imperative form:

- Cuando hables con una persona mayor, usa *usted* en vez de *tú*.

If you want to use the verb *dirigirse*, you cannot easily use the *pasiva refleja*, because *dirigirse* is a pronominal verb that already contains a *se*. In this case, you either use the imperative form:

- Cuando te dirijas a una persona mayor, usa *usted* en vez de *tú*.

or use *uno* as the subject, if you want to make it more general:

- Cuando uno se dirige a una persona mayor, usa *usted* en vez de *tú*.

The form *usares* is **future subjunctive**. This tense is almost never used anymore, so you can safely forget about it. It only appears in some legal texts, referring to events that may happen in the future. For example "A person who **causes** harm to another without provocation shall be guilty of assault": the word *causes* would be in future subjunctive. In almost all non-legal contexts, the present subjunctive is used for this purpose instead.